# Use Multiple Email Footer Magento 1

Tags: email, email-templates, transactional-mail, footer

I want to Add Different footers for the different emails from the Admin.

Comment: You can design template from admin it self, and then use those template on specific location.

Comment: Can you please share the configurations for this

Comment: Can you tell me, for example which email template you want to edit?

Comment: Actually I have many email templates for many events. I want to use different footer for the different templates. How Can I do with the admin Magento 1

Answer (score 0):

1. You can edit any email from this options.

   ```
   Magento Admin -> System -> Transactional Email
   ```

You can edit email template from there and save the updated email template from there.

2. Now you need to send this updated email template for the event where you needed updated email template.

Comment: Actually I have many email templates for many events. I want to use different footer for the different templates. How Can I do with the admin Magento 1

Comment: @RanaZain  Check above answer is that things only. Update each template from here and then set updated email template for particular event. So that will send new updated email template for that event.

Comment: Is it not possible to add 2 footers for the transactional emails? Actually I want to use 2 footers for 2 different email templates?

Comment: @RanaZain in edit section, you can do anything what you want.

Comment: Okay, But where I can set the path for Footer 2? Because we set the footer for the all email templates in the configurations?

Comment: @RanaZain I told you to edit the template which you want, then it affected that particular email template it self. And into that edit section you already design the footer what you want, then why you needed path there? Hope now things is clear to you.

Comment: Okay. Let me check and if need then I will get back to you!

Comment: If answer help, accept and upvote, so it will help other into community.